# CKEditor 5 image attributes conversion

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to convert some image attributes when inserting an imageurl in CKEditor 5. I want to convert the image tag  to an image tag with some data attributes .

````
editor.conversion
    .for('downcast')
    .elementToElement( {
        model: 'imageInline',
        view: ( modelElement, { writer } ) => {
            console.log(modelElement);
            const imgSrc = modelElement.getAttribute('src');
            return writer.createContainerElement(
                'img', { src: imgSrc.split('?')[0], 'data-source': imgSrc }
            );
        },
        converterPriority: 'high'
    } )
    .attributeToAttribute( {
        model: {
            name: 'imageInline',
            key: 'source'
        },
        view: modelAttributeValue => ({
            key: 'src',
            value: modelAttributeValue.split('?')[0]
        })
    } );```


I managed to create a downcast converter which adds the data-source attribute but the src attribute isn't updated in the editor source? It should contain the url without query parameters.
I tried setting the src in both the elementToElement conversion as in the attributeToAttribute conversion.
````